# Python3 tkinter DLL load failed

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, python-3.9

I want to start a tkinter application with python3.9, but I get the following error:

```py
>>> import tkinter as tk
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-e89bfb5dd03b>", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk

  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Is there a way to configure python3.9 for tkinter? I don't use cx_Freeze, but normal python interpeter.

Comment: Are you executing the file from the terminal?

Comment: No, I use ipython from spyder3

Comment: Does the quesiton and answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61684957/14316282

Comment: I don't think so... Also, I'm using Windows via virtualbox, my host OS is Ubuntu 20.04, which works fine. In another computer with virtualbox, tkinter runs normally on Windows